# Developing Computer Vision app with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, computer-vision

I'm quite new to iphone development and I was wondering is there any API which able used in Xcode?

I know OpenCV and I found this:
http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/

Just wondering is it reliable?

Comment: I've never used it but it was written in c++ and xcode compiles c++. It was optimized for intel but I can't see any issues with the a4. Might be less than optimized but should be solid.

Comment: You might need to be a little more specific.  What, exactly, are you trying to recognize or process in images or video within your application?

Answer (score 4):

I have already 2 apps up in the AppStore with OpenCv.
Is very fast even on iPhone. The best resource online for learning how to use OpenCV on iOS is from Yoshimasa Niwa. [OpenCV Yoshimasa Niwa](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/). Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

iOS is now officially supported in OpenCV. See installation instructions here: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation

As noted by Stephane, its not a good idea to mix Objective C with C++. Often, you would have to change the file extention from ".m" for Objective C to ".mm" for Objective C++ for it to compile properly. Even so, it is best to isolate all your computer vision code, especially those using C++, into a class (or a number of classes) and write an Objective C class as a wrapper for that class. This is so that the rest of your system will only interact with an Objective C class rather than the C++ behind it.

As of XCode v4+, some IDE operations do not work well when dealing with C++ code. For e.g., if you try to refactor a class that has C++ code in it (the file has extension ".mm"), XCode will tell you it cannot perform the operation because its dealing with C++. Hence, its a good idea to isolate C++ from the Objective C code.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is completely dedicated to Computer Vision, it's therefore a good catch. As madmick3 said, it's not very fast, but usually a good start to do computer vision operations. I just would be careful about mixing Objective C and C++, that's usually not a good idea, at least until XCode 4 is not officially out.

In order to compile and install OpenCV for iOS, look at [this link](http://www.atinfinity.info/wiki/index.php?OpenCV%2FUsing%20OpenCV%202.2%20on%20iOS%20SDK%204.2), it worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

for simple vision problems listed below.. you can use iOS built in framework vision available from iOS 11 ... Opencv can be used on complex vision problems and some times bit slow

Face Detection and Recognition
Machine Learning Image Analysis
Barcode Detection
Image Alignment Analysis
Text Detection
Horizon Detection
Object Detection and Tracking

little exploration  at https://github.com/gunapandianraj/iOS-Vision